# How to redirect Post requests using TIdHTTPProxyServer

Tags: c++, delphi, indy10, c++builder-xe2

Currently I want to redirect specific Post requests using Indy10 TIdHTTPProxyServer. I followed the page

http://embarcadero.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.internet.winsock/200904/0904301714.html

and wrote a simple sample as follow.

```
oid __fastcall TForm3::MyProxyHTTPBeforeCommand(TIdHTTPProxyServerContext *AContext)
{

    if (AContext->Target == "http://example.com/need_redirect_url" ) {

        TIdIOHandler* io = AContext->Connection->IOHandler;

        io->WriteLn("HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily");
        io->WriteLn("Location:  http://exampledomain.com/target_url");
        io->WriteLn("Connection: close");    
    }
}
```

It works if I press the "http://sample.com/need_redirect_url" into the URL bar of the browser.
But return nothing(No matter Post or Get) if it is a XMLHttpRequest which is targeted to the same URL.

I have to admit I am really unfamiliar with how HTTP works. And I also wonder if there is any better way to do what I want.

Although I am using C++Builder XE2. Delphi samples are also appreciated as there are less examples using indy components using C++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is not writing a blank line that terminates the HTTP headers you are sending.  You will also need to throw an exception to prevent `TIdHTTPProxyServer` from navigating to the client's requested URL after the `OnBeforeCommand` event handler exits.

Try this:

```
void __fastcall TForm3::MyProxyHTTPBeforeCommand(TIdHTTPProxyServerContext *AContext) 
{ 
    if (AContext->Target == "http://xxx.com/need_redirect_url" )
    { 
        TIdIOHandler* io = AContext->Connection->IOHandler; 

        io->WriteLn("HTTP/1.0 302 Moved Temporarily"); 
        io->WriteLn("Location: http://mydomain.com/target_url"); 
        io->WriteLn("Connection: close");     
        io->WriteLn("");     

        Abort();
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Currently I can successfully receive expected response in proxy.  However there is another problem. The Post request becomes Get request after redirecting. Should I do any other things when it is Post request?

Comment: Changing a `POST` request to a `GET` request is simply what some HTTP clients (erroneously) do when receiving a `302` response. This behavior is described in [RFC 2616 Section 10.3.3](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.3.3). For an HTTP 1.1 request, use `303` instead to preserve a `POST`.

Comment: Thanks, Although after I use "HTTP/1.1 303 See Other" instead it still does not work. I am not pretty sure it is a proxy issue or an user agent issue. For this question I think you already give me a perfect answer. (However I still want to know why 303 does also not work..)

Comment: My bad. `303` is supposed to convert a redirect to a `GET`. Use `307` instead, which is supposed to preserve the original request.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a `XMLHttpRequest` cross-domain policy problem, because `example.com` != `mydomain.com` - see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Cross-domain_requests for background information and potential solutions

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am not sure it is a cross-domain issue as I also did not receive the expected responses in proxy. Furthermore, I already used XMLDomainRequest in IE8 and it worked fine when the target of the request is http://mydomain.com/target_url